# Writing loops to get input from each cell in .csv to use for another program

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate number of positive words using python3 (using Loughran and McDonald (LM) dictionary). In each cell of the second column of a *.csv file has news collected from a website.

```
import csv
def read_cell(x, y):
     with open('final.csv', 'r') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       y_count = 0
    for n in reader:
        if y_count == y:
            cell = n[x]
            return cell
        y_count += 1
```

Following a post, I tried to the above, I want to get each cell (e.g. read_cell(1,1)) as input for the below code (refer: LM) :

```
TARGET_FILES = r'....'
file_list = glob.glob(TARGET_FILES)
   for file in file_list:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as f_in:
        doc = f_in.read()
    doc_len = len(doc)
```

I have two problems: (a) the code cannot read the news information from cell (1,1). (b) How can I create a loop for all the cells in the .csv file? 
The output will be in a *csv file. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you check out `pandas` for reading .csv files, specifically `pandas.read_csv()`. Look e.g. here to get started: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html

Comment: Thank you. I have already gone through it. But it is not helping.